# What version of ‘unittest2’ is needed for Python 3.4 features?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, backport

What version of the `unittest2` library do I need for the [new features in Python 3.4's `unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#unittest)?

The third-party [`unittest2` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2/) is a very useful back-port of Python 3's `unittest` features, to work on older Python versions. By importing that third-party library, you can use the features described for Python 3's `unittest` in your Python 2 code.

There are some [handy new features](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#unittest) in Python 3.4's `unittest` library. (In particular I'm trying to use the “subtests” feature in a way that will just keep working when we migrate to Python 3.)

To use those features in Python 2, what version of `unittest2` do I need to install?

Answer (score 3):

I've done a bit of digging in the repository, and it looks like:

- Subtests were added in 0.6.0 ([this commit](https://hg.python.org/unittest2/rev/0daffa9ee7c1))
- SkipTest was added in 0.6.0 ([this commit](https://hg.python.org/unittest2/rev/f0946b0ba890))
- The discover changes were added in 0.6.0 ([this commit](https://hg.python.org/unittest2/rev/d94fdb8fd3a8))
- Test dropping was added in 0.6.0 ([this commit](https://hg.python.org/unittest2/rev/503d94dea23a))

I can't find any commits at all about `mock()`, so I can only presume that it isn't available or maintained. Otherwise, everything you want is in 0.6.0 or above (but I recommend you just get the latest anyway).